# how to cut the string at the time of update in gridview?

Tags: c#

I m displaying the image file in gridview.
At time of update I want to show only the file name to update and not the extension.
like file1.jpg is there but i should only change file1 and not .jpg
how to do that?

Comment: First tell me is your grid is data bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string filename = "file1.jpg";
string filenameonly=filename.Substring(0,filename.LastIndexOf('.'));
```

Comment: in this case when i click edit it shows me file1 only but when i click update i need to be again show upadatedfilename.jpg.

Comment: @user755230: I am expecting that your gridview is taking data from database. If that is the case then first you have to update your database then your grid will show updated file name.

Comment: here issue is for extension,that when i click edit it sholdnot show .jpg or whatever extension and when update is finished it should again show complete file name as file2.jpg likewise

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Path API as follow

```
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(*filePath*);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample:

```
var fName = "test.1.jpg";
var noExt = fName.Remove(fName.LastIndexOf('.'), fName.Length - fName.LastIndexOf('.'));
Console.WriteLine(noExt);
```

The noExt variable contains the string you need.